# Using `$toLong` in MongoDB C# Queries

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm struggling to convert the below Mongo aggregation pipeline into its C# equivalent. I am trying to convert `ISODate`s to unix timestamps using the built in [`$toLong`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/#mongodb-expression-exp.-toLong). There could be millions of documents, so doing `.ToList().Select(x => ConvertToTimestamp(x.date))` is not feasible.

Say I have the following documents:

```
[
  {
    "value": 100,
    "date": ISODate("2022-03-26T04:38:28.044Z")
  },
  {
    "value": 50,
    "date": ISODate("2022-03-26T04:38:28.044Z")
  },
  {
    "value": 23,
    "date": ISODate("2022-03-26T04:38:28.044Z")
  },
  {
    "value": 199,
    "date": ISODate("2022-03-26T04:38:28.044Z")
  }
]
```

I have the following aggregation query that works

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    date: {
      $toLong: "$date"
    },
    value: 1,
  }
})
```

And I get the expected output

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "date": NumberLong(1648269508044),
    "value": 100
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "date": NumberLong(1648269508044),
    "value": 50
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "date": NumberLong(1648269508044),
    "value": 23
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "date": NumberLong(1648269508044),
    "value": 199
  }
]
```

Now, the question is, how to do this with the fluent aggregation API in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1: Pass aggregation query as `BsonDocument`.**

```cs
var pipelineDefinition = new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument
    {
        {
            "$project", new BsonDocument
            {
                { "date", new BsonDocument { { "$toLong", "$date" } } },
                { "value", 1 }
            }
        }
    }
};

List<Model> result = _collection.Aggregate<Model>(pipelineDefinition)
    .ToList();
```

---

**Approach 2: Work with `BsonSerializer`.**

1. Implement `IBsonSerializer` class to convert from `DateTime` type to `long` type.

```cs
public class DateToLongConverter : IBsonSerializer<long>
{
    public Type ValueType => typeof(long);

    public long Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var bsonReader = context.Reader;
        return bsonReader.ReadDateTime();
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, long value)
    {
        var bsonWriter = context.Writer;
        bsonWriter.WriteInt64(value);
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
    {
        var bsonWriter = context.Writer;
        bsonWriter.WriteInt64((long)value);
    }

    object IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var bsonReader = context.Reader;
        return bsonReader.ReadDateTime();
    }
}
```

2. Apply `BsonSerializer` attribute with `DateToLongConverter` to `Date` property.

```cs
public class Model
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    [BsonSerializer(typeof(DateToLongConverter))]
    public long Date { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

3. Register class map for `Model` class.

```cs
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Model>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();

    cm.MapMember(x => x.Date)
        .SetSerializer(new DateToLongConverter());
});
```

4. To query data:

```cs
List<Model> result = (await _collection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument()))
    .ToList();
```

> Demo

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with Approach 1, as I don't *always* want to deserialize to a timestamp, only for this specific query. The first approach is good enough for me and I have marked this as the answer. Follow-up question: is it possible to do the above without using `BsonDocument`? If possible, I would prefer to use the fluent API, as this has the additional benefit of type safety. I see that $toLong is mentioned in the [csharp mongo repo](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amongodb%2Fmongo-csharp-driver%20toLong&type=code) but I couldn't make sense of how to use it.